# Postgresql psql: error: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "userrole"

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu

I have installed PostgreSQL and created a user 'userrole' with superuser privileges. Also able to connect through python code.

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(
   database="postgres", user="userrole", password="userroot", host='127.0.0.1', port= '5432'
)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select version()")
data = cursor.fetchone()
print("Connection established to: ",data)
conn.close()
```

This is my output:

```
Connection established to:  ('PostgreSQL 12.6 (Ubuntu 12.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, 64-bit',)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The issue I'm facing is through CLI is cannot connect to this user:

```
(venv) resh@project:~/PycharmProjects/utilities$ sudo su -l userrole
[sudo] password for resh: 
su: user userrole does not exist
```

Sorry, I am new to ubuntu, now I have changed the command and still getting an issue :

```
(venv) resh@project:~/PycharmProjects/utilities$ sudo psql -U userrole
[sudo] password for resh: 
psql: error: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "userrole"
```

Comment: A database user is different from an operating system user. `su` is about operating system users.

Comment: Now i am trying to access psql user and still facing the issue @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Since I don't know what you are doing, I cannot say what you are doing wrong. Perhaps edit the question and add the new command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your latest psql attempt is trying to connect over the Unix socket, which is (apparently, based on error message) configured to user peer authentication.

To use the password, you need to connect over TCP, like your python is doing:

```
psql -U userrole -h 127.0.0.1
```

Also, the sudo is useless for password-based authentication, so I removed it

Answer (score 1):

`userrole` is an SQL user.  It is not a Linux user.  The two user lists are completely separate.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by using following command in Ubuntu:

```
psql -d database -U username -h 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

- Open the pg_hba.conf file using any text editor. It is located at `/etc/postgresql/[major.minor]/main/pg_hba.conf` eg `/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf` location.
- Change the following line

  ```
  local   all    postgres        peer
  ```

  to

  ```
  local   all    postgres        md5
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Searched and scoured the web for a answer who will fix the problem.
In my case it was solved simply by adding this line

> TYPE  DATABASE        USER   ADDRESS       METHOD

> local  all          youruser                  md5